# C File Handling - Integer Value 13 Cannot Be Written Into Files

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I'm unable to write the integer value 13 into a file using any of the file handling functions available on C including `putw()`, `fprintf()`, and `fwrite()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
  int i;
  int arr[]={10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
  FILE *fp;
  if (fp = fopen("test", "w")) {
        for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
            putw(arr[i], fp);
        }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen("test", "r");
  while ((i=getw(fp))!= EOF) {
        printf("%d, ",i);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  getch();
}
```

gives an output

```
10, 11, 12, 3584, 3840,
```

and a modified array

```
int arr[]={13, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
```

gives an output

```
2816, 3072, 0, 14, 15,
```

You can notice that the output is not as expected after encountering the **value 13**.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Working on Windows I take it?

Comment: Yes, Windows XP SP2, and now I know why this happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like CR/LF line ending processing. Open your files in binary mode by using the "b" mode modifier, i.e.:

```
  if (fp = fopen("test", "wb")) {
  fp = fopen("test", "rb");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot aib! It certainly was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly smells like CR/LF processing. The reason for this is that 13 is ASCII for CR... I would go with dealing with it as a binary file leaving you in charge of line ending issues!